# Vue cannot read property of undefined for attribute of object but only in template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a variable created in vue with

```
    data() {
        return {
            plans: [],
}
```

Plans is later given objects pushed to it. When I print that object in the js it gives `{id: 'filler', name: 'Premium', priceId: 'filler', price: '10000'}`. I can also get the name specifically with `console.log(this.plans[1]['name'])`  and it will give 'Premium' correctly. However, in the template I'm trying to display the name with `<h1>{{plans[0].name}}</h1>` (I also tried as ['name']) and it says Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name'). However, if I just give it `<h1>{{plans[0]}}</h1>` it shows the entire object correctly. Very confused what I'm missing, please let me know if any more info is needed.

EDIT: the array is populated with the following

```
    async getPlans(){
        
        const db = getFirestore()
        const productsRef = collection(db, "products")
        const productsQuery = query(productsRef, where("active","==", true))
        const productsQuerySnap = await getDocs(productsQuery)
        // console.log(productsQuerySnap[0])
        // const temp = []
        for (let i = 0; i<2; i++){
            // const doc = i.docs
            console.log(productsQuerySnap.docs[i])
            const pricesRef = collection(db, "products", productsQuerySnap.docs[i].id, "prices")
            const pricesQuerySnap = await getDocs(pricesRef)
            const name = productsQuerySnap.docs[i]["_document"]["data"]["value"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["name"]["stringValue"]
            console.log(pricesQuerySnap.docs[0]["id"])
            const priceId = pricesQuerySnap.docs[0]["id"]
            const price = pricesQuerySnap.docs[0]["_document"]["data"]["value"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["unit_amount"]['integerValue']
            console.log({id: productsQuerySnap.docs[i].id, name: name, priceId: priceId, price: price})
            this.plans.push({id: productsQuerySnap.docs[i].id, name: name, priceId: priceId, price: price})
        }
        console.log(this.plans[0]['name'], "plans is running")
    

  },
```

it was run in mounted

Comment: Including more related code will be helpful in finding out the issue.

Comment: @sachuverma what segment of the code are you referring to?

Comment: Try adding where you are accessing `plans` array elements, from where you are getting this variable from, etc.

Comment: `if I just give it <h1>{{plans[0]}}</h1> it shows the entire object correctly` does it have `name` key in it when you do this?

Comment: @sachuverma the exact thing it shows if I show that is {id: 'filler', name: 'Standard', priceId: 'filler', price: '10000'}

Comment: From where are you getting this `plans` array, is it hard coded or fetched from api or something else? `"Cannot read properties of undefined"` from this it looks that `plans[0]` is undefined when you tried to access its `name` key.

Comment: @sachuverma i pushed to it in a method. I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if there is a solution utilizing methods and mounted, but I got around the issue by using setup() rather than methods and mounted. I set the value of a ref to the full object array and then returned the value at the end of setup and everything was properly accessed in the template.

Comment: Please provide some code to better explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Always, always make sure data's available before accessing it in the template. These types of errors *(cannot read property undefined of...)* mostly occur due to a lack of checking first.

In your case, before accessing the `plans array` or `plans' key (plans[0])`, make a computed property or directly apply a condition at the template to check if it is available in the DOM, like this-

1. If you want to loop on all plan items-

```
<template>
  <div v-if="plans && plans.length">
     <template v-for="(item, index) in plans">
       <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
     </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

2. If you want to display only a single item-

```
<template>
  <div v-if="plans && plans.length && plans[0]">
    <h1>{{ plans[0].name }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Recommended-**

Instead of writing `plans && plans.length` directly in the template, you can create a computed property for it, and access anywhere without repeating the code-

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isPlansAvailable">
     <template v-for="(item, index) in plans">
       <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
     </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "ComponentName",
    
    data() {
      return {
        plans: [],
      }
    },
  
    computed: {
      isPlansAvailable() {
        return this.plans && this.plans.length;
      }
    },
    
    mounted() {
      // YOUR API METHOD
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 data() {
        return {
            plans: Object,
}
```

Comment: plans is not an object it's an array of objects

Comment: I understand, but have you tried it this way!

Comment: just tried it, did not work unfortunately

Comment: can you capture the screen after you  give it like <h1>{{plans}}</h1>, but make sure plans : Object.